# unable to integrate open_id_authentication with ActionController::API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, openid, rails-api

I am buidling rails application with my `ApplicationController` building on `ActionController::API`. I tried integrating [`open_id_authentication`](https://github.com/Velir/open_id_authentication) gem and it worked fine if my ApplicationController was built using `ActionController::Base` but threw error with API. I tried including middleware in following manners

Method 1. Add middleware in initilaizer

```
    `config/initializers/openid.rb`
     require 'open_id_authentication'
     Rails.application.config do
      config.middleware.use OpenIdAuthentication
      
      config.after_initialize do
        OpenID::Util.logger = Rails.logger
        ActionController::API.send :include,  OpenIdAuthentication::ControllerMethods
      end
     end
```

but got following error stack with it:

```
    NoMethodError - undefined method `authenticate_with_open_id' for #:
      app/controllers/v2/sessions_controller.rb:45:in `accounts_authentication'
      app/controllers/v2/sessions_controller.rb:17:in `login'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
      activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
      actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
      rack-openid (1.4.2) lib/rack/openid.rb:98:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
      activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
      activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
      activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
      better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
      better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
      better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
      web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
      web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
      railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
      railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
      railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
      activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
      railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
      railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
      /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
      /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
```

Method 2. Add middleware via config/environment/development.rb

```
require 'open_id_authentication'
 Rails.application.configure do
  config.middleware.use OpenIdAuthentication::Middleware
 end
```

It gave the same error stack

Please help me with the solution to include middleware for open_id_authentication in ActionController::API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the middlewares included using command `rake middleware` and I found that `OpenIdAuthentication::Middleware` was already included. Going through [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api#other-middlewares) README, I added `config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride` to `config/environments/development.rb`.

Now, to access `open_id_authentication` gem methods, include it in whichever module/controller you are using via `include OpenIdAuthentication::ControllerMethods` as `ControllerMethods` module has all the methods being used.